# Codeception - comment() to HTML outside of the Cest

Tags: php, automated-tests, customization, codeception

I have extended 'test.fail' (as shown in Extension section of http://codeception.com/docs/08-Customization) method and I want to print some debug line straight to the HTML report , But I can't get to the comment() method same as it is possible when I am inside Cest test.

I want to use something like:

```
 comment("TEST FailEvent!");
```

instead of

```
codecept_debug("TEST FailEvent!");
```

in the code below:

```
class MyCustomTestEventHandler extends \Codeception\Extension
{
public static $events = array(
    'test.before' => 'beforeTest',
    'test.fail' => 'testFailed'
);

public function beforeTest(\Codeception\Event\TestEvent $e) { }

public function testFailed(\Codeception\Event\FailEvent $e) {
    codecept_debug("TEST FailEvent!");
}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I am using this workaround...

Place this in your Acceptance Helper Class:

```
    public function seeMyVar($var)
    {
       $this->debug($var);
    }
```

In your Cest Test:

```
    $fail = "TEST FailEvent!";
    $I->seeMyVar($fail);
```